# QT draw coordinate system arround QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, coordinate-systems, qgraphicsscene

I would like to draw coordinate system on top and left side of my QGraphicsView.

Gimp is a perfect exemple of what i would like to do: [image]

Should I implement it by myself using foreground function ? Does there is a dedicated QWidget ?

Comment: See: http://www.qcustomplot.com/

Comment: Anyway to do something similar with a stock QT ? I don´t want to use another libraries

Comment: Sorry, for simplicity I only know of libraries like that, you can always look into the documentation for that library to see how they do it.